# Is $\operatorname{Span}\{x,x^2\}$ a subspace of all polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Consider the subset $S=\operatorname{Span}\{x,x^2\}$ within $P$, the set of all polynomials. Is $S$ a subspace of $P$? Justify your answer by using either the one- or two-step subspace test.

My first instinct was to expand on the given information. $S=\operatorname{Span}\{x,x^2\}$ became any polynomial of the form$$c_1x+c_2x^2$$ and $P$ became the set of every possible combination of $a_i$, $x_i$, and $n$ in $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$$ thus we can say $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in P$$ It would also seem to follow that, if $n=2$, $a=c$, and $a_0=0$, then $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=c_2x^2+c_1x+0=c_1x+c_2x^2\in P$$However, this doesn't prove anything by either of the subspace tests. By the two-step subspace test, I need to show two things:

1. Show that if $s_1,s_2\in P$, then $s_1+s_2\in S$.
2. Show that if $s_1\in P$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$, then $bs_1\in S$.

> (1) If $s_1=c_{11}x_1+c_{12}x_1^2,s_2=c_{21}x_2+c_{22}x_2^2\in S$, then $s_1+s_2=c_{11}x_1+c_{12}x_1^2+c_{21}x_2+c_{22}x_2^2$.

My problem is that, to my knowledge, there is no way to transform $s_1+s_2$ into a form of a polynomial within $P$. Is there away or is $S$ not a subspace of $P$? Perhaps $s_1=x$ and $s_2=x^2$?
**EDIT:** So it seems my mistake was in assuming that the value of $x$ could vary.

> (1) If $s_1=c_{11}x+c_{12}x^2,s_2=c_{21}x+c_{22}x^2\in S$, then $s_1+s_2=c_{11}x+c_{12}x^2+c_{21}x+c_{22}x^2=(c_{11}+c_{21})x+(c_{12}+c_{22})x^2$, which can be rewritten as $a_1x+a_2x^2\in S$.
> (2) If $b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $s_1=c_{11}x+c_{12}x^2$, $bs_1=b(c_{11}x+c_{12}x^2)=(bc_{11})x+(bc_{12})x^2$, which can be rewritten as $a_1x+a_2x^2\in S$.

Comment: First, $S$ is not equal to $c_1x+c_2x^2$, $S$ is the the set of all polynomials of this form (not a single polynomial).

Comment: I do not get the point of the question you were asked. By definition $\textrm{Span}(x,x^2)$ is the smallest subspace containing $x$ and $x^2$. What is your definition?

Comment: Why do $s_1$ and $s_2$ have different subscripts on $x$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Well, as you said, $S$ is the set of all polynomials of the form $c_2x^2+c_1x$ so I assumed that $s_1$ and $s_2$ could have different values for $x$.

Comment: @Jordan: $x$ is not anything but a placeholder variable. It does not actually "have" a value when you're talking about the polynomials by themselves. Sure, you can apply them as functions, but that's not what's happening here - you're looking at the functions themselves, not the outputs.

Comment: @Deusovi : In fact, polynomials are not the same as polynomial functions. Polynomials can be interpreted as functions, but in algebra one learns that it is possible for two polynomials to correspond to the same function, the best example being the polynomial $x^p-x$ in the field of integers modulo $p$. However, in characteristic zero (such as over the field of real numbers), the application which sends a polynomial to its polynomial function is injective. A polynomial is just defined as its sequence of coefficients and addition/multiplication is defined "in the obvious way".

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Oh, I didn't realize that - thanks for the correction! That's really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $0\in S$. Let $f_1(x),f_2(x)\in S$ where $f_1(x)=ax^2+bx$ and $f_2(x)=cx^2+dx$, and $k\in\Bbb R$, we have:
$$f_1(x)+f_2(x)=(ax^2+bx)+(cx^2+dx)=(a+c)x^2+(b+d)x=(f_1+f_2)(x)$$
and,
$$k(f_1)(x)=k(ax^2+bx)=(ka)x^2+(kb)x=(kf_1)(x)$$

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now. Why is $x$ allowed to stay $x$ throughout the proof? Rather, why do $c_1$ and $c_2$ become new variables $a, b, c$ and $d$ respectively but $x$ is always $x$? Is this the nature of span?

Comment: I chose $a,b,c,d$ to be arbitrary scalars, but you could have used $c_1,c_2,...$. The reason that these are arbitrary is because any function in $S$ is a linear combination of the monomials $x$ and $x^2$, so the scalars are to represent an arbitrary linear combination of these basis elements. The variable $x$ remains the same in each function because this is variable of the basis monomials which span the subspace. So this does not change between the functions in the span, it remains the same $x$.

Comment: When thinking of the polynomials as a vector space, think of the powers of $x$ as your unit vectors. For example, think of $1,x,x^2$ as the unit vectors $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}$ in $\mathbb R^3$. If you add in more powers of $x$, you up the dimension. They are vectors in your vector space where as $a,b,c,d,c_1,c_2$ are all scalars in a field (usually real or complex numbers). It is important to differentiate scalars from vectors in this way when studying abstract vector spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Any element of $S$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors. So if $v \in S$ then $v=ax^2+bx$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$.

Suppose $v_1=a_1x^2+b_1x$ and $v_2=a_2x^2+b_2x$. Then $v_1,v_2 \in S$ and for some scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$\alpha v_1+ \beta v_2= (\alpha a_1 +\beta a_2)x^2+(\alpha b_1 +\beta b_2)x$$
where $\alpha a_1 +\beta a_2$ and $\alpha b_1 +\beta b_2$ are scalars. So $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. If it is required to show that the zero vector is in $S$ simply pick $a=b=0$.